# Why is there a special access to Maramureș on Ukrainian side

Tags: borders, hiking, romania, ukraine

Next month, I'm having a trip to Ukraine and then to Romania through [Marmaros masif](https://www.google.com/maps/@47.8291953,24.4645038,9z?hl=en). However while seeking info, I've also found on [Czech General Consulate in Lviv sites](http://www.mzv.cz/lvov/cz/viza_a_konzularni_informace/informace_pro_obcany_cr/vstup_do_pohranicni_zony_marmarosskeho.html), that I need a special permission.

Briefly, it contains this:

- Fill and send application for entry
- Arrive to arranged checkpoint
- Give everyday details about our yourney
- Send SMS about our position daily

So why is this access quite so strict? What if I don't have signal the whole day so I cannot inform border security about my position. I would be grateful for anybodys experience share.

Comment: A good question, if any of those are enforced at all, at least on Ukrainian side.

Comment: So you are heading from Ukraine to Romania or vice versa?

Comment: @Suncatcher, only from Ukraine to Romania.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a part of [Carpathian Biosphere Reserve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpathian_Biosphere_Reserve), part of which is listed on the UNESCO World Heritage Sites as part of the [Primeval Beech Forests of the Carpathians and the Ancient Beech Forests of Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primeval_Beech_Forests_of_the_Carpathians_and_the_Ancient_Beech_Forests_of_Germany).

Therefore The Nature Reserve Fund of Ukraine considers it a protected area and limits access to it.